# How to apply validation to textbox in which date written in dd/mm/yyyy format in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to store date in textbox in dd/mm/yyyy format and not to use DatePicker.
How to apply validation to textbox in which date written in dd/mm/yyyy format in wp7?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
const string DateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

public bool ValidateDate(string dateToCheck)
{
    try {
        DateTime.ParseExact(dateToCheck, DateFormat, null);
    }
    catch {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply we can use like this

```
string date = DateTime.Parse(string_type_date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

it works for me.